# Copy a file to build directory with Qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I want to copy file to destination folder.
I tried this code:

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    SetupTool.ini

    DESTDIR_WIN = $${DESTDIR}
    DESTDIR_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
    PWD_WIN = $${PWD}
    PWD_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
    for(FILE, OTHER_FILES){
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cmd /c copy /y $${PWD_WIN}\\$${FILE} $${DESTDIR_WIN}$$escape_expand(\\n\\t))
    }
```

But it did not work.

Comment: I added the Qt-Creator tag because Qt is the framework not the ide. I am not even sure Qt is needed as the displayed part of a .pro file is not at all related to the framework.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it in the past:

```
    copyCommand = @echo Copying application data...
    copyCommand += && $(COPY) \"$$PWD/some_file.ext\" \"$$OUT_PWD\"

    copyTarget.commands = $$copyCommand
    first.depends = $(first) copyTarget

    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copyTarget
```

Comment: I have done it by setting QMAKE_POST_LINK to the command to run. I needed it in Visual Studio, and I seem to recall the extra targets method does not work in VS.